# Find the default phase that a Maven plugin binds to

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Given a `<plugin>` element in a `pom.xml`, how do I find the default phase that it binds to?

For example, I'd like to know which phase of the Maven lifecycle does the `maven-war-plugin` gets executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to see what's really happening in your project along those lines is with `mvn help:effective-pom`. It doesn't just show the defaults; it shows what actually is according to your current pom.

Comment: As mentioned by pointyhat this does not work in all cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309652/how-can-i-find-out-the-default-phase-a-maven-goal-binds-to for a better way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having a problem with the above-reply.

Here's a simple pom. It uses an annotation processor plugin, which is bound to `generate-sources` by-default, since I didn't specify a `<phase>`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-simple</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`mvn generate-resources` does indeed invoke the plugin...

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-simple 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.0.5:process (default) @ test-simple ---
```

Yet scanning the output of `mvn help:effective-pom` doesn't yield any clue to the default binding of this plugin.

```
$ mvn help:effective-pom |grep generate-sources; echo $?
1
```

The only way I've so-far found to list default phase binding is by examining plugin source.