# How can I find out the default phase a Maven goal binds to?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

In Maven, how can I find out the default phase of a goal (if any default phase exists at all for this particular goal)?

#### Example

I am using a Maven plugin called [Jetty Maven Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin). It contains a goal `jetty:run`. Running the command `mvn jetty:run` (notice this command only contains a goal, not a phase) first builds a `pom.xml`-specified web application up to the default [`test-compile` phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), then deploys it inside a Jetty server.

As pointed out in the [Mojo API Specification](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html), a goal can have a default phase assigned to it in its source code (via `@phase` or via `@execute phase`). [In case of `jetty:run`, the default phase is `@execute phase="test-compile"`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/8.1.4.v20120524/org/mortbay/jetty/plugin/JettyRunMojo.java/?v=source).

But finding the source code file can get quite complicated. Is there an easier way for finding out the default phase?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the [maven-help-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html) like the following:

```
mvn help:describe -DartifactId=maven-compiler-plugin -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -Dgoal=compile -Ddetail
```

which will printout many information but in the first lines:

```
[INFO] Mojo: 'compiler:compile'
compiler:compile
  Description: Compiles application sources
  Implementation: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo
  Language: java
  Bound to phase: compile

  Available parameters:
  ....
```

If you try that for jetty:run like this:

```
mvn help:describe -DartifactId=jetty-maven-plugin -DgroupId=org.mortbay.jetty -Dgoal=run -Ddetail
```

You will get a large output but you won't see a default phase, cause it's intended to be called from command line:

```
[INFO] Mojo: 'jetty:run'
jetty:run
  Description: This goal is used in-situ on a Maven project without first
    ....
    redeploying.
     .....

  Implementation: org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo
  Language: java
  Before this mojo executes, it will call:
    Phase: 'test-compile'

  Available parameters:
      ....
```

Comment: @khmarbaise how can we do this in m2e plugin?

Comment: You can call Maven from inside m2e as well. But better to use the command line.

Comment: also it's possible to introspect specific version using additional parameter `-Dversion=1.3.72`